# Is it possible use Programmers Notepad as an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, notepad

Is it possible that to embed [Programmers Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org) into Eclipse so it opens in the same window, on right click - history, local .... ?

I would like have in Eclipse the text editor capabilities of Programmers Notepad - such as  syntax coloring, etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eclipse+syntax+highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin called [EclipseColorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/). It has syntax-highlighting for many languages...